# create a dictionary from a text file, which contains a key and a set made from multiple properties

Tags: python, dictionary

The text file contains the names of cheeses and its properties. The number of properties is not the same for each cheese. 
An end result is a dictionary with the names of each cheese being a key and its properties being the set linked to that key.

Is there a different way than manually copying each set of properties into a set and assigning the correct key?

```
champignon de luxe garlic,soft,soft-ripened,garlicky,herbaceous,herbal,spicy,cream,creamy,natural
bleu dauvergne,semi-soft,artisan,buttery,creamy,grassy,herbaceous,salty,spicy,tangy,strong,ivory,creamy and smooth,bloomy
```

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open(filename) as cheeses:
    cheese_rows = csv.reader(cheeses)
    d = {cheese_row[0]: set(cheese_row[1:]) for cheese_row in cheese_rows}
```

This will create a dictionary with keys of the first value in each row in the file, and values of a set of the rest of values in the row.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the text in line by line.
2. Split the fields by comma (or use the `csv` module)
3. add them to a dictionary

Giving the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys

# Empty dictionary to hold Cheese properties
CHEESE = {}  

try:
    fin = open("cheese.txt")
except:
    sys.stderr.write("Failed to open input file\n")
    sys.exit(1)

# EDIT: more comprehensive error catching
line_count = 0
try:
    for cheese_data in fin: # or  fin.readlines():
        line_count += 1
        # We're expecting name,property1,property2, ... ,propertyN
        fields = cheese_data.strip().split(',')
        if ( len( fields ) > 1 ):
            cheese_name = fields[0].capitalize()
            cheese_properties = fields[1:]
            # Add item to dictionary
            CHEESE[cheese_name] = cheese_properties
except:
    sys.stderr.write("Error around line %u\n" % (line_count))
finally:
    fin.close()

### ... do stuff with CHEESE dict

print(str(CHEESE))
```

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code, e.g. the error handling if the file doesn't exist, checking if `len(fields) > 1`, capitalizing the cheese name, it's all a distraction and uncalled for. Data is a nondescript word, it's all data. `readlines` is inefficient, the filehandling won't close in the case of an exception, is unidiomatic, `print` will convert `CHEESE` to a string no need to call `str`, etc, etc.

Comment: I agree with Peter. I think the steps you gave were great but the code is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: @PeterWood - The "irrelevant code" is there as a nudge to the OP that they should think about these things when writing their own code.  I assumed, that because they asked for help with such a simple operation, that they're quite a beginner at programming and aspects such as input-data integrity and error checking need to happen.

Comment: Why post non-idiomatic python to a beginner? Surely they deserve better, not worse?

Comment: Because non-idomatic code, in this case, is much more readable and understandable.  Each step is a single operation which can be split-out and absorbed in isolation.  Terse, idiomatic answers are great among software engineers, but not for absolute beginners.